# Prove the two sets have the same cardinality by forming an appropriate mapping.

Tags: real-analysis

For each pair of sets below, prove they have the same cardinality (i.e. by constructing an appropriate mapping f : A → B) or explain why they do not. 
i) A = {1, 3, 5, 7} and B = {11, 33, 66, 99}.

Obviously they have the same cardinality because they have the same number of elements but I can't find a bijective function to relate the two. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** It's perfectly fine to specify a function by listing the ordered pairs that make it up. You don't have to write some single formula that works for all of the numbers. (After all, what if you have $B=\{ \textrm{circle}, \textrm{square}, \textrm{triangle}, \textrm{pentagon}\}$?)

Answer (score 0):

With finite sets like these it's perfectly fine to define a function by just listing what it does to each element: by setting $f(1)=?$, $f(3)=?$, $f(5)=?$, $f(7)=?$.

Just try to construct a function by listing the image of each element like this, and it will probably turn out to be bijective.